# Найти и заменить слова в строке

Tags: javascript, node.js

Мне нужно найти в строке слова, которые длиннее 3 символов, которые не обрамлены тегами и которые сами не являются тегами.

У меня получился такой код:

```js
function replaceLongWords(str) {
  // Регулярное выражение для поиска слов длиннее трех символов,
  // не являющихся тегами и не находящихся внутри тегов
  const regex = /(?<!<[^>]*)\b\p{L}{4,}\b(?![^<]*>)/gu;
  
  // Функция обратного вызова для замены найденных слов
  function replaceCallback(match) {
    // Код замены слова
    // Например, заменим слово на его длину
    return match.length.toString();
  }
  
  // Замена найденных слов с помощью функции обратного вызова
  const replacedStr = str.replace(regex, replaceCallback);
  
  return replacedStr;
}

const inputString = "Это пример <b>текст</b> с некоторыми <span>test</span> словами длиннее трех символов, которые не являются тегами, и которые не находятся внутри <i>каких-либо</i> тегов.";
const result = replaceLongWords(inputString);
console.log(result);
```

но проблема в том что он не видит почему-то русских слов.

буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: напишите в консоли `'ыв sd'.replace(/\p{L}/gu, '1')`

Comment: `\p{L}` работает с кириллицей в js, но вот граница слова `\b` нет

Comment: Набросал пример: https://regex101.com/r/LvWZl5/1

Answer (score 0):

Можно решить проблему так:

```
let str = "Это пример <b>текст</b> с некоторыми <span>test</span> словами длиннее трех символов, которые не являются тегами, и которые не находятся внутри <i>каких-либо</i> тегов."
```

Убираем все тэги и всё что внутри них:

```
const regexp = /<[^>]+>[^>]+>/g;
str = str.replaceAll(regexp, "")
```

Убираем знаки препинания:

```
const exclude = [".", ",", ":", "!", "?"]
for (e of exclude) {
    str = str.replaceAll(e, "")
}
```

Разбиваем на слова и выводим их:

```
for (word of str.split(" ")) {
    if (word.length > 3) {
        console.log(word)
    }
}
```

Не совсем понятно в чём именно задача, просто получить такие слова или именно заменить их, если заменить то можно искать полученные слова с помощью `indexOf` и заменять